# Can a vacuum tube convert tube heat to power

Tags: physics, vacuum-tube

In playing with the triode component in the Falstad simulator, I often observe behaviors that seem nonsensical, with a tube sometimes acting as a power source.  If a triode just had three connections for the anode, cathode, and grid, this would obviously be impossible based upon conservation-of-energy laws.  Unlike a transistor, however, an isolated-filament vacuum tube would have a source of energy: the filament heater.  As such, it would seem plausible that depending upon the material coatings of the electrodes, the temperature differential between the cathode and anode could create a potential difference.  I doubt that for any normal tube the effects would be as significant as in the simulator, but I'm curious whether the effect would normally exist, and how significant it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is a well-known effect, sometimes exploited as a free grid bias power supply. https://tubes.njunis.net/?p=256&lang=en